# Looking for a better statement to use rather than an if statement with sql query

Tags: php, mysql

I am running a query and need it to pick from one field and score the user according to race and gender.

I tried the if statement to look for the query and select the correct score but it either picks the first if statement and doesn't check the rest even if the query is different when the approve button is clicked.

```
//Approve Button Rating
                if(isset($_POST['approveBtn'])){
          $query ="UPDATE bbee SET status=1 WHERE id='$id' AND race='Black'";

                        if(mysqli_query($connection,$query))
                        {?>
                            <div class="successmsg alert alert-autocloseable-success">
                            <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
                            <p align="center">
                                You are a level 1 B-BBEE Contributor
                            </p>
                            </div>
                        <?php 
                        }else{
                        ?>
                            <div class="errormsg alert alert-autocloseable-danger">
                                <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
                                <p align="center">
                                    An error occured, Could not disapprove business
                                </p>
                            </div>
                        <?php 
                        }
                }

                if(isset($_POST['approveBtn'])){
                    $query ="UPDATE bbee SET status=2 WHERE id='$id' AND race='White'";

                    if(mysqli_query($connection,$query))
                    {?>
                        <div class="successmsg alert alert-autocloseable-success">
                        <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
                        <p align="center">
                            You are a level 2 B-BBEE Contributor
                        </p>
                        </div>
                    <?php 
                    }else{
                    ?>
                        <div class="errormsg alert alert-autocloseable-danger">
                            <a href="#" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</a>
                            <p align="center">
                                An error occured, Could not disapprove business
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    <?php 
                    }
            }
```

I am looking for a better statement to use because even this statement runs both results and doesn't show one result.

Comment: Are you saying that `if(mysqli_query($connection,$query))` is always true?

Comment: Yes if the query is true then it gives back the result.

Comment: The queries are not failing because the UPDATE works but it simply doesn't update any rows. So, you probably want to check the [`affected_rows`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php).

Comment: It doesn't seem to affect one row, the status does change but should it select from the next if statement it prints out the first and the actual result out.

Answer (score 0):

You do know that your code is written in a way that BOTH the queries get executed in case

if(isset($_POST['approveBtn']))

is true, do you ? I'm not sure this really was what you wanted...

As someone has already said, UPDATE queries are successful even when they don't update any record (you should check affected rows), but beware of inserting the $id in the query as you're doing in your code as that may be open to SQL injections.

Comment: Sorted, put a affected rows element and changed the If statement.